# Uso de reCAPTCHA en validación de formularios

Tags: php, mysql, captcha

mi pregunta va por lo siguiente: Estoy camino a desarrollar una webApp usando php y MySQL y a pesar a que no se compromete información delicada, no quiero dejar de lado la seguridad por lo que me preguntaba si es relevante incluir reCaptcha en el inicio de sesión de usuarios, para evitar ataques de fuerza bruta? Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Qarilucas, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

referente a lo que comentas, dependerá mucho en donde pienses implementar dicha aplicación, hacia que usuarios va dirigida, cual sea el nivel de transacciones estimado para dicha aplicación, si se va a usar en Internet o en una Intranet. En mi experiencia personal, mientras mas facilites el logueo, el usuario final tomara tendencia a entrar a dicha aplicación. Podrías dejarla con usuario y contraseña cifrado con la seguridad del lado del servidor y posteriormente en alguna transacción importante, meter el reCAPTCHA. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @LaresF. La aplicación va a usarse en internet y los usuarios serán empleados de la empresa para la que se haría el desarrollo. No hay información delicada, pero si quiero tener cuidado con ataques de fuerza bruta por lo que pensaba hacerlo tal como comentas, usuario y contraseña cifrada con blowfish y aumentar un reCaptcha para mayor seguridad. Además estaba pensando incluir un honeypot y en caso de que se llene este campo redirigir al usuario. Voy a trabajar en el código para mostrarles una guía.